# Opening Facebook app with another ? With the "Twitter way"

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

My app needs to display a Facebook account. So I would like the Facebook application opens or if it is not available, the web browser. Currently I can open the Twitter app with this way and the system ask what to do (Twitter app or the browser).
Here is the code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewProfile); // Create an instance of WebView and set it to the layout component created with id webview in main.xml
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/"+name); // Specify the URL to load when the application starts
myWebView.setInitialScale(1); // Set the initial zoom scale
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // Initialize zoom controls for your WebView component
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); // Initializes double-tap zoom control
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("BumpMe");
```

This method is very good and I want to have the same result for Facebook. Currently I can open the Facebook app like that:

```
String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/info?user="+fbid;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But if the application is not installed it won't work...

How can I do it like for twitter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason this works with Twitter is that the Twitter app handles https://mobile.twitter.com/* URL's in its intent filters; so when you issue an intent that has that URL, the Twitter app gets called. So the only way to do this with Facebook (or any other app) would be to use a URL that matches one of the patterns declared in its intent filters. Maybe http://m.facebook.com/... ?

Comment: Ok, and how can I know if an application handle a specific link pattern ? Is there a list somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of offering the user the choice of app or browser, another way is to try to open the app, and if that fails to open the web page. Here is how I do that for Twitter:

```
long userID = tweet.getUser().getId();
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=" + userID));
    startActivity(intent);
}catch (Exception e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=" + userID))); 
}
```